# How to make CounterIncrement step in increments of 2

Tags: counting

Is it possible to make counters that step in increments other than 1?  The default for `CounterIncrements` seems to be 1 and there's no other documentation on what you can do with it.  Ideas?

I can see this being useful.  For example, creating solutions to odd numbered questions in a homework set.

The following code creates a style definition for "ItemNumbered" that increments by one.

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["ItemNumbered"], 
     CellDingbat -> 
      Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["ItemNumbered"], "."}], 
       FontWeight -> "Bold"],
     CellMargins -> {{81, 10}, {4, 8}},
     StyleKeyMapping -> {"Tab" -> "SubitemNumbered"}, 
     CellFrameLabelMargins -> 4, 
     CellChangeTimes -> {3.657516045744032`*^9},
     CounterIncrements -> "ItemNumbered", 
     CounterAssignments -> {{"SubitemNumbered", 
        0}, {"SubsubitemNumbered", 0}}, MenuSortingValue -> 1630,
     FontFamily -> "Arial",
     FontSize -> 15, Global`ReturnCreatesNewCell -> True]},
   WindowSize -> {808, 751},
   WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 20}, {16, Automatic}}, 
   FrontEndVersion -> 
    "10.3 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (October 9, 2015)",
    StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

Notice you can test this by creating a blank "ItemNumbered" Cell.  Then press enter 5 times and you get...

1.
2.
3.
4.
5.

I would like to alter the code to increment in steps other than one like two for example.  I would like...

1.
3.
5.

Comment: take a look at `AddTo` construct - [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AddTo.html)

Comment: I get the idea, but I don't think this can be applied to the CounterIncrements option.

Comment: could you add the small example of the code that you are dealing with?

Comment: @garej - I included some code with explanation.  Thank you!

Comment: Horrible hacky idea: insert an invisible cell in between the cells you actually want, so as to get 1, 2(invis), 3, 4(invis), 5, …

Comment: haha!  ya... that's pretty hacky.  But maybe "hacky" is the only way to go...

Comment: `CounterIncrements -> {"ItemNumbered", "ItemNumbered"}` will give `2. 4. 6. 8. ...` There may be some way to start at `1.`

Comment: Wow!  Impressed!  ty!  I figured out how to get odd... see answer below....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works.  Thank you for the help!

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
     CounterAssignments -> {{"ItemNumbered", -1}}]

    SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
     StyleDefinitions -> 
      Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
        Cell[StyleData["ItemNumbered"], 
         CellDingbat -> 
          Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["ItemNumbered"], "."}], 
           FontWeight -> "Bold"], CellMargins -> {{81, 10}, {4, 8}}, 
         StyleKeyMapping -> {"Tab" -> "SubitemNumbered"}, 
         CellFrameLabelMargins -> 4, 
         CellChangeTimes -> {3.657516045744032`*^9},
         CounterIncrements -> {"ItemNumbered", "ItemNumbered"}, 
         CounterAssignments -> {{"SubitemNumbered", 
            0}, {"SubsubitemNumbered", 0}}, MenuSortingValue -> 1630, 
         FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 15, 
         Global`ReturnCreatesNewCell -> True]}, WindowSize -> {808, 751}, 
       WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 20}, {16, Automatic}}, 
       FrontEndVersion -> 
        "10.3 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (October 9, 2015)",
        StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Random user don't know what really is the answer here, could you rephrase it so it will be more handy for future visitors? :) p.s. take a look at the comment I've made under WReach answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[]
, StyleDefinitions -> Notebook @
  { Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]]
  , Cell[StyleData["ItemNumbered"], CounterBoxOptions -> {CounterFunction -> (#*2-1&)}]
  , Cell[StyleData["SubitemNumbered"], CounterBoxOptions -> {CounterFunction -> (#*2-1&)}]
  , Cell[StyleData["SubsubitemNumbered"], CounterBoxOptions -> {CounterFunction -> (#*2-1&)}]
  }
]
```

As pointed out by @Kuba, the same `CounterFunction` must be applied to items, sub-items and sub-sub-items to ensure that the counters at all levels match.

Example:

```
Do[
  If[j === 1 && k === 1, CellPrint@Cell["item", "ItemNumbered"]]
; If[k === 1, CellPrint@Cell["subitem", "SubitemNumbered"]]
; CellPrint@Cell["subsubitem", "SubsubitemNumbered"]
, {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 2}
]
```

[image: list items]

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it affects what is shown not the value of the counter so SubItemNumbered won't match partent Item.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, the same `CounterFunction` must be used at all levels (a surprise to me).  I have updated my answer to reflect that.  Thanks.